# Creating a project specific Vosk dictionary

Tags: speech-to-text, kaldi, vosk

I am working on an application which uses Vosk for speech recognition. I would like to create a dictionary for the application which contains only the trigger words and spoken numbers needed by the application. Using command line instructions found here: [www.alphacephei.com/vosk/adaptation](http://www.alphacephei.com/vosk/adaptation)  I was able to install Kaldi on my laptop. These are,

```
export KALDI_ROOT=`pwd`/kaldi
git clone https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi
cd kaldi/tools
make
extras/install_opengrm.sh
```

However, I am having a problem building a dictionary using the provided commands. These are,

```
export PATH=$KALDI_ROOT/tools/openfst/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$KALDI_ROOT/tools/openfst/lib/fst
cd model
fstsymbols --save_osymbols=words.txt Gr.fst > /dev/null
farcompilestrings --fst_type=compact --symbols=words.txt --keep_symbols text.txt | \
ngramcount | ngrammake | \
fstconvert --fst_type=ngram > Gr.new.fst
mv Gr.new.fst Gr.fst
```

The problem occurs at "cd model" because there is no /model directory in the directory structure created during the Kaldi installation. Checking in my Vosk project, I find /models, but no /model directory either.

I have tried creating /model in /kaldi/tools and then running the above commands with no success. Please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The command `cd model` in the docs is actually incomplete. To run this you have to `cd` into the directory where `Gr.fst` exists. This file usually exists in the directory `<any model with dynamic graph>/graph`.

1. Head to https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models, download a model that supports dynamic vocabulary reconfiguration (usually small models do, big models don't).
2. Unzip the folder
3. Prepare a .txt file with words that your project relates to.
4. Proceed with the steps mentioned in your second code snippet (with a slight modification to the `cd model` part)

Comment: Thanks Scotrraaj, I will work through this.

Comment: Alright, let me know if it goes well! @portsample

Comment: If my solution was helpful, please vote my answer. Thank you.